# LINQ Results differ from SQL Server View

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have a LINQ Query that simply filters the results from a view that already exists on our SQL Server.  The Problem that I am having is that the results coming in from the LINQ query are different than the results on the SQL server.

First I have created the EF connection through the wizard in VS.  I create a context by a basic:

```
using(Entities context = new Entities())
            {
```

then the Linq Query is simply:

```
var Active = context.vwUniqueParts
.Where(a => a.HasOrders == true)
.ToList();
```

The problem is that I am getting repeated results in the returned data:

Where I would expect to see:
Part1, Part2, Part3, Part4, Part5, Part6, Part7, Part8, Part9

I instead get:
Part1, Part2, Part2, Part2, Part2, Part6, Part6, Part6, Part9

When looking at the results certain results will be repeated and then after a while it stops repeating.  When it stops repeating the part that shows up is correct for it's place in the data set.

Comment: Can you show us your UniqueParts view and the sql query you're running by hand to get the correct results? Also, you can see the generated sql query to cmpare by using tostring like `context.vwUniqueParts.Where(a => a.HasOrders == true).ToString()`... that might point you in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though the primary key on the model does not match the database.  If they differ, you'll find that the result set will return odd results such as you are seeing here.

Comment: This is not an **answer**.You should post it as a **comment** instead.

Comment: I think it does have something to do with the SQL primary key -- it was a generated RowID, and did not seem to be generating unique keys.  I ended up using a different query as I was spending too much time debugging the small program.  I'm not sure what the solution would have been to get it all working correctly, but this answer helped me to get the program working, so I am accepting it as the answer.